# ¿Es más correcto decir "uno de ellas" o "una de ellas?"

Tags: género

"Uno de ellas" tiene más resultados en Google, pero hay bastante resultados para "una de ellas" tambien . ¿Es posible que ambos son correctos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo correcto es "una de ellas", debe coincidir el género de los dos elementos. En el DPD hay una entrada que trata la [concordancia](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5#38) y dice sobre esto en particular:

> **3.8. Construcciones partitivas.** Las construcciones partitivas están formadas por un primer elemento, que ha de ser un cuantificador,
>   y un segundo elemento, introducido por la preposición *de*, que es,
>   bien un sustantivo precedido de determinante, bien un pronombre; el
>   primer elemento designa la parte, mientras que el segundo designa el
>   todo: *una de las participantes, la mitad del público, muchos de
>   nosotros*, etc. Si ambos elementos tienen flexión de género, debe
>   haber concordancia forzosa entre ellos: *«Rusa educada en Estados
>   Unidos, Meir [...] fue una de las firmantes de la declaración de
>   independencia de Israel»* (GmnzBarlett Deuda [Esp. 2002]); *«Lidia
>   Ariza [...] dijo que se considera una de las mejores actrices de este
>   país»* (Dedom [R. Dom.] 14.1.97); por tanto, cuando se utilizan
>   cuantificadores con flexión de género (uno -na, muchos -chas, varios
>   -rias, etc.), no es correcto usar el femenino en la designación de la parte y el masculino en la designación del todo, aunque con ello se
>   pretenda señalar que la parte aludida pertenece a un colectivo mixto:
>   ⊗*«Se escucharon las proposiciones de Míriam Orellana, [...] una de
>   los académicos invitados»* (Hoy [Chile] 7-13.12.83); ⊗*«Usted es una
>   de los alumnos más brillantes de que goza la Facultad»* (Bain Dolor
>   [Col. 1993]); debió decirse, respectivamente, una de las académicas
>   invitadas, una de las alumnas más brillantes.

Como vemos no es correcto decir "uno de ellas" pero tampoco "una de ellos" aunque el masculino se utilice para definir a un grupo mixto.

Answer (score 2):

Al hablar de ellas, te estás refiriendo a un conjunto de partes totalmente femeninas, con lo que uno de los individuos sería femenino y por tanto debes usar  **una**.

En mi opinión lo más correcto es decir "una de ellas".

Comment: En realidad usar _una_ no es "lo más correcto". ¡Es lo correcto!.

Comment: @DGaleano - Sin embargo, mucha gente dice "lo más correcto" aún cuando es una situación blanco y negro.